# Display a chart in Real time using the data coming from .CSV files in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am trying to display a real time graph using the data coming from different csv files, i need to take the data from the latest csv file and display it.I am new to ASP and i am using MVC3.

This is my controller code for graph:

```
            string[] _yval = ReadFile2ArrayFromChannel3();
            var bytes = new Chart(width: 1600, height: 100)
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Line", legend: "Abc", xField: "t", yFields: "mv",
                // xValue: _xval,
             yValues: _yval)
            .GetBytes("png");
            return File(bytes, "image/png");
```

ReadFile2ArrayFromChannel3() function is taking the data from a csv file. I want to know how to change the values in runtime, since this graph controller is only being called once when i click on the action link from my ASP page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what exactly needs to change at runtime and why.

Comment: May be this https://github.com/riyadparvez/csv-to-chart can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a real time chart, you are using the wrong approach.  My I suggest you look into something like [Telerik Chart](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/chart/highperformance) or [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update)